# How to Use BTsync's file sharing by Bluetooth?

Tags: network, bluetooth, android

I established the bluetooth connection between the devices. 
However, the speed download/upload still stays low (< 1 MB/s) between the devices while it should be much higher with Bluetooth 4.0 in both devices: Macbook Air Mid-2013 (adapter) and Samsung Galaxy S4. 
BTsync should use local network to share data between the devices in the sharing.

I contacted the BTsync support about the issue

> Unfortunately we don't support bluetooth
>   so Sync establishes connection through LAN or internet, if there are
>   firewalls and NATs it can be established through relay server. But
>   Sync uses the best possible connection for synchronization. We'll
>   don't plan supporting bluetooth in nearest future but we'll think
>   about it.

So it is completely technically possible to support file sharing in the local network by Bluetooth.

---

How can you enable BTsync file sharing by bluetooth in OS X with Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature request is now active in their development. 
However, it can take some years to get it because of limited resources in their development. I will let you know when I get more pieces of information about the issue. There are some tickets which has to be solved before such a feature can be implemented.